# How to execute jQuery using Selenium2Library under Robot Framework

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am new to robot framework,

and want simulate control the jQuery component via executing jQuery

However, the Selenium2Library almost drives me crazy.

try to get value of the DOM component but the log shows NONE.

refer to http://d.pr/i/KXhw

The following is my test code.

Thanks in advance.

```
click configuration
    [Tags]    xpath
    Open Browser    http://${host}    ie
    Log   "123"
    ${slide val}=    Execute JavaScript    window.jQuery("#gain_slider_handle").val();
    ${title}=       Execute JavaScript      window.$("head title")[0];
    ${t2}=          Execute JavaScript      window.eval('window.document.title')
    Log     ${slide val}
    Log     ${title}
```

And I try to use Python to do the same thing via selenium webdriver,

it also get the "None" value .

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Ie(r"C:\\bin\\IEDriverServer.exe")
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    self.base_url = "http://172.19.1.28/setup/media/sensor.html"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True
def test_py_robot(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url )
    print "title:" + str( driver.execute_script("document.title"))
    print "wdr val:" + str( driver.execute_script("$('#wdr_strength').val()") )
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use jquery selector,you need to make sure web is loaded jquery package.
if without,you can Execute JavaScript

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")[0];var newScript = document.createElement('script');newScript.type='text/javascript';newScript.src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';headID.appendChild(newScript);
```