# How to execute a JQuery with robotframework

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, robotframework

I am trying to execute a jQuery via robot framework on the system under test. When i execute the following line on browsers console:

```
window.jQuery('--ELEMENT PATH--').val();
```

I am getting the value i'm looking for. But when i execute the same line with robot framework (calling keyword "Execute Javascript"):

```
${element val}  Execute javascript return window.jQuery('--ELEMENT PATH--').val();
```

The result is always NONE even if the element has a value.

Is it possible to do what i pretend? If not, i will accept suggestions.

Ps: I am doing it using jQuery because i have to test on many browsers, including IE11. If it wasn't because of IE11 i could have done it with normal javascript or selenium keywords. And also the element i am trying to get the text does not have the text on html, only in the object.

Comment: When you are executing the JavaScript, are you sure the JQuery library is loaded? See for example this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608211/how-to-execute-jquery-using-selenium2library-under-robot-framework

Comment: @am9417, Thank you for your comment. The error was in the element Path. The jQuery library is not even loaded. Don't know how but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The way to execute a jQuery is exactly like it was shown in the answer:

```
${value}   Execute Javascript     return window.jQuery('ELEMENT PATH').val()
```

I wasn't getting the value because the element path was wrong.